# Does not contain text condition - Visual Basic

Tags: string, vb.net

I'm doing a simple web crawl in Visual Basic.  I am receiving the following error code when trying to run the below code;

```
Do While headingStart <> -1 And _
testText.Substring(testText.Substring(headingStart + 35), 34) <> _
"<span class=^media-prefix voices^>"
```

The error is;

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion from string "UK to send warship to
>   South Chin" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

The problem revolves around the **omitText.Substring[...]** onwards (without this part of the code it works, but provides the data I don't need also).

I'm not sure why it's recognising an Integer, as it's a substring within a substring I'm searching?

As an FYI, the following code/variables being used within this are;

**headingStart;**

```
Dim headingStart As Integer = Source.IndexOf(heading)
```

**heading;**

```
Dim heading As String = "<span class=^media-prefix ^></span>"
```

**testText;**

This just contains all the HTML/XML downloaded from the website which is then crawled upon.

**Note:** The headingStart + 35 starts the index **after** the code in heading

**Note:** The 34 in the Left function is the length of the text I'm trying to omit ()

I'm still very much a learner at VB, so my mistake may be routine, however I'm stumped at this point!

Thanks,
Hugh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Substring`-method takes one or two arguments, both integers.

- 1. `startIndex`
- 2. `length`

But this returns a string:

```
testText.Substring(headingStart + 35)
```

So your code should rather look like following:

```
testText.Substring(headingStart + 35).Substring(0,34) <> "<span class..."
```

But you can do it with one `Substring`-call:

```
testText.Substring(headingStart + 35, 34) <> "<span class..."
```

Comment: You're right - I've got a bit blinkered and overcomplicated - thanks for the clarity, the one substring call works as you said it would :)